# Python - ¿Cómo cambiar el valor de un dataframe en bucle en función del dato anterior?

Tags: python, pandas, bucle-for, dataframe

Estoy intentado completar un dataframe con valores horarios.

`C = Dataframe` en cuestión. Tiene valor para la hora `00:00` y quiero que el mismo valor se repita 24 veces, es decir, para todas las horas. El dato que existe es una media diaria, por lo cual, quiero el mismo dato que hay para la hora `00:00` para el resto de las horas.

Lo que intento realizar en mi código es leer un archivo e introducirlo en un dtaframe, y posteriormente intentar recorrer la columna del dataframe 'C' para cuando haya un valor `0.0`, tome el valor anterior, así, cuando se encuentre una celda con un dato, lo repita hasta el siguiente.

```
C = pd.read_csv('513_SS_050207_091210.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
C.columns=['Fecha', 'SS1']
for index, row in C['SS1'].iteritems():
    if row == 0.0:
        C.replace({'SS1':{0.0:'Valor Anterior'}),inplace = True)
       
    else:
        None
```

```
C: 
29/07/11 21:00  0
29/07/11 22:00  0
29/07/11 23:00  0
30/07/11 00:00  27658,625
30/07/11 01:00  0
30/07/11 02:00  0
30/07/11 03:00  0
30/07/11 04:00  0
30/07/11 05:00  0
30/07/11 06:00  0
30/07/11 07:00  0
30/07/11 08:00  0
30/07/11 09:00  0
30/07/11 10:00  0
30/07/11 11:00  0
30/07/11 12:00  0
30/07/11 13:00  0
30/07/11 14:00  0
30/07/11 15:00  0
30/07/11 16:00  0
30/07/11 17:00  0
30/07/11 18:00  0
30/07/11 19:00  0
30/07/11 20:00  0
30/07/11 21:00  0
30/07/11 22:00  0
30/07/11 23:00  0
31/07/11 00:00  32617,125
31/07/11 01:00  0
31/07/11 02:00  0
31/07/11 03:00  0
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es obtener un dataframe con los datos completos de esta forma:

```
29/07/11 21:00  0
29/07/11 22:00  0
29/07/11 23:00  0
30/07/11 00:00  27658,625
30/07/11 01:00  27658,625
30/07/11 02:00  27658,625
30/07/11 03:00  27658,625
30/07/11 04:00  27658,625
30/07/11 05:00  27658,625
30/07/11 06:00  27658,625
30/07/11 07:00  27658,625
30/07/11 08:00  27658,625
30/07/11 09:00  27658,625
30/07/11 10:00  27658,625
30/07/11 11:00  27658,625
30/07/11 12:00  27658,625
30/07/11 13:00  27658,625
30/07/11 14:00  27658,625
30/07/11 15:00  27658,625
30/07/11 16:00  27658,625
30/07/11 17:00  27658,625
30/07/11 18:00  27658,625
30/07/11 19:00  27658,625
30/07/11 20:00  27658,625
30/07/11 21:00  27658,625
30/07/11 22:00  27658,625
30/07/11 23:00  27658,625
31/07/11 00:00  32617,125
31/07/11 01:00  32617,125
31/07/11 02:00  32617,125
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Buen día @GuilleGL, bienvenido a la comunidad. ¿Podrías agregar algunas filas de tu  `dataframe` para poder ver como se conforman los datos? También agrega un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para poder reproducir el problema y un ejemplo del resultado que esperas obtener. En cuanto agregues la información faltante reviso nuevamente tu pregunta para poder ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: Espero que haya quedado un poquito más claro. Perdona y muchas gracias!.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Resuelto!

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable **no** utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces `apply` podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

Una forma muy fácil de hacerlo es utilizando [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) con el método `ffill` (Forward fill, es decir, rellenar hacia adelante).

**Nota adicional:** Como no pusiste tus datos tuve que crear un `dataframe` genérico que tendrás que adaptar. Siempre agrega algunas filas de tus datos para que las respuestas reflejen lo que deseas lograr.

Ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col 1': ['00:00', '01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00',
                             '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00',
                             '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00',
                             '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00'],
                   'Col 2': [9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
print('Dataframe original')
print(df)

# Reemplazar los 0 con el último valor diferente de cero
df['Col 2'] = df['Col 2'].replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')

print('Valores reemplazados')
print(df)
```

Esto imprime:

```
Dataframe original
    Col 1  Col 2
0   00:00      9
1   01:00      0
2   02:00      0
3   03:00      0
4   04:00      0
5   05:00      0
6   06:00      0
7   07:00      0
8   08:00      0
9   09:00      0
10  10:00      0
11  11:00      0
12  12:00      0
13  13:00      0
14  14:00      0
15  15:00      0
16  16:00      0
17  17:00      0
18  18:00      0
19  19:00      0
20  20:00      0
21  21:00      0
22  22:00      0
23  23:00      0
Valores reemplazados
    Col 1  Col 2
0   00:00      9
1   01:00      9
2   02:00      9
3   03:00      9
4   04:00      9
5   05:00      9
6   06:00      9
7   07:00      9
8   08:00      9
9   09:00      9
10  10:00      9
11  11:00      9
12  12:00      9
13  13:00      9
14  14:00      9
15  15:00      9
16  16:00      9
17  17:00      9
18  18:00      9
19  19:00      9
20  20:00      9
21  21:00      9
22  22:00      9
23  23:00      9
```